# Android How to make self-relationship in ORMLite?

Tags: android, database, foreign-keys, ormlite

I have the following object that is a self-relationship, as follows:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "categoria")
public class Categoria implements Serializable {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    public int id;

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = true, foreign = true)
    public Categoria pai;

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, width = 50, unique = true)
    public String descricao;

    public Categoria() { }
}
```

When I do this:

```
Categoria cat = new Categoria();
cat.pai = null;
cat.descricao = "Comidas";

categoryDao.create(cat); //should be id = 1.

Categoria sub_cat = new Categoria();
sub_cat.pai = cat;
sub_cat.descricao = "Bebidas";

categoryDao.create(sub_cat); // should be id = 2.
```

So my object Categoria is null when do this:

```
Categoria sub_cat = categoryDao.queryForId(2);

sub_cat.descricao // is ok, return "Bebidas".
```

but

```
sub_cat.pai // is null when supposed to be sub_cat.pai.id = 1.
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just after `categoryDao.create(cat); //should be id = 1.`, is the id in fact 1? Also, are you using a DatabaseConfigUtil, and if so, did you run it after changing the schema? Did you recreate the table after changing the schema? Maybe check the logcat for SQLExceptions.

Comment: Hi, I don't make changes, the schema was create in the first time I created my OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper object that call onCreate() where create the database based in my Categoria class.

Comment: Are you sure `sub_cat.pai` is `null`?  Or could it be one of the other fields in `sub_cat.pai` is null.  ORMLite you create the object but only the `sub_cat.pai.id` field should be set.