# Self-relationship in ORMLite android

Tags: java, android, ormlite

Possible duplicate: [Android How to make self-relationship in ORMLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961470/android-how-to-make-self-relationship-in-ormlite) 
I have the same problem with above question, but I doesn't find the answer. 
My table look like:

```
  ---------------------
  CATEGORY
  ---------------------
  id            (Integer)
  name          (Text)
  parentId      (Integer)
  ---------------------
```

What I expect:

```
 @DatabaseTable (tableName = "Category")
  public class Category{
      @DatabaseField (generatedId = true)
      private int id;

      @DatabaseField
      private String name;

      // how to map this one?
      private Category parent;
 }
```

Please tell me how can I map the parent - child relationship? I want use the `Category` like this:

```
 Category parent = new Category();
 parent.name = "parent";

 Category child = new Category();
 child.setParent(parent);
```

**Another thing**: How can I get all children of Category with Dao? Does I have to use Sql query?

 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tested it and i am not sure if there will be any errors but you can use:

```
@DatabaseField(canBeNull = true, foreign = true)
private Category parent;
```

check the `canBeNull = true` in case a category is the top Category with no parents.

and

```
@ForeignCollectionField
private Collection<Category> childs;
```

try this.

Comment: I have edited your answer to work for my case: removed the `foreignAutoRefresh` (it gave duplicate record when inserting since it re-check foreign key) and `eager` (because I don't need lazy load), added the column name for parent id. Now it works like a charm. You should accept my edit.